# sending a list value in a Post request's body to validate Pydantic model

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I'm using FastAPI, Pydantic, SQLAlchemy, and Postgres to build a service that receives post requests and stores the data on the database. There is a **List** in the Pydantic model like the following:

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class Note(base model):
    id: int
    title: str
    authors: List[str]
```

And the table:

```
notes = Table(
    "notes",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("title", String),
    Column("authors", ARRAY(String(50), dimensions=3)),
)
```

Here is the way I do the post request, when there is not a **List** value:

```
def post(payload: Note):
    query = questions.insert().values(title=payload.title)
    return database.execute(query=query)
```

Post request's body:

```
{
    "title": "some value"
}
```

And it works fine. But adding the **List** value breaks it with Pydantic's validation error:

```
def post(payload: Note):
    query = questions.insert().values(title=payload.title, authors=payload.authors)
    return database.execute(query=query)
```

```
{
    "title": "some value",
    "authors": ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
}
```

> value is not a valid list
>
> type_error.list

How can I change the post function and request body, to make this work?

Edit: The traceback:

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 385, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/saeed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 149, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/saeed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 102, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/saeed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/home/saeed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/home/saeed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/home/saeed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/home/saeed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 550, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/saeed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 227, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/saeed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 41, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/home/saeed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 204, in app
    response_data = await serialize_response(
  File "/home/saeed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 126, in serialize_response
    raise ValidationError(errors, field.type_)
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Note
response
  value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)
```

Comment: If that's the body, it isn't valid json.  Where is it coming from?  (well, it is valid, but it isn't useful)

Comment: I've tried some sorts of bodies (with double quotes, without it, etc) but none of them was correct. What is the valid JSON for a body with a list item? @snakecharmerb

Comment: Should be `["name1", "name2", "name3"]`  - double quotes around the strings in the list, no quotes around the list itself

Comment: Hum, this one returns error in my case too: `  value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)
` @snakecharmerb

Comment: Can you try `Column("authors", ARRAY(String(50), dimensions=1))` (with the json I suggested)?  If that doesn't work, can  you provide the traceback?

Comment: @snakecharmerb changing the `dimension` didn't help.
I added the traceback to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. The problem resolved by fixing the `respone_model` that has an error, and all I was doing for storing the data was correct.

```
@router.post("/", response_model=Note, status_code=201)
def create_note(payload: Note):
    note_id = post(payload)
    response_object = {
        "id": note_id,
        "title": payload.title,
        "authors": payload.authors,
    }
    return response_object
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail why this fixed your issue?

Answer (score 0):

```py
@router.get("/fetchusuarios", response_model=List[providers.schemas.User])
async def fetchall_users(db:Session=Depends(get_db)):
    usuarios = db.query(models.usermodel.User).all()
    return usuarios
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Django-Ninja (based on FastAPI) and had the same error. Originally, my decorator was like this:

```py
@router.get('/apartment-sale-hanoi/', response=List[ApartmentSaleHanoiSchema])
```

I fixed `value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)` just by removing `List` from the response model as following:

```py
@router.get('/apartment-sale-hanoi/', response=ApartmentSaleHanoiSchema)
```

my returning response (displayed as JSON) was a list of objects

```py
response = ApartmentSaleHanoi.objects.all()
```